# AttributeError: 'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'timestamp'

Tags: python, date, datetime, timestamp

My code is:

```
get_closest_date = []
get_amounts_sum = []
query = """SELECT sp.customer_surname, sp.amount, cp.amount, sp.monthly, sp.date_ FROM set_payment7777 sp JOIN customers_payments7777 cp ON cp.customer_AFM = sp.customer_AFM  WHERE cp.date_ <= %s AND sp.date_ <= %s GROUP BY sp.customer_AFM"""
mycursor.execute(query,(to_date,to_date,))
for row in mycursor:
    get_closest_date.append(row[4])
                        


cloz_dict = {abs(datetime(int(to_year_drop.get()), int(to_month_drop.get()), int(to_day_drop.get())).timestamp() - date.timestamp()) : date for date in get_closest_date}
res = cloz_dict[min(cloz_dict.keys())]

print(res)
```

and my imports are:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import os 
import mysql.connector
from tkinter import ttk
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime
```

but I keep getting: AttributeError: 'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'timestamp'

Comment: What are you after here, exactly?  The `date` object doesn't have a `timestamp` option because it doesn't include time.

Comment: I think this is a good question because date objects ***do have*** a `fromtimestamp` method, so "does not include time" can't be the whole story here it seems to me.

Answer (score 2):

[date](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#date-objects) objects have no `.timestamp()` method as a datetime object has. As a ***work-around***, you can create a datetime object from it by using `combine`:

```
from datetime import date, datetime

d = date(2020, 1, 1)
dt = datetime(2020, 1, 1) # for comparison

print(dt.timestamp())
print(datetime.combine(d, datetime.min.time()).timestamp())
# 1577833200.0
# 1577833200.0
```

`date` objects have a [fromtimestamp](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromtimestamp) method, so the lack of the inverse actually seems inconsistent to me. Just as that would truncate the time information given by the timestamp, a `timestamp` method would have to implicitly use a time - e.g. 0 hours in the local time zone (as date objects are naive). If anybody has a good explanation, please comment :)